# Does Ignite Spring Data @Query annotation support concept of projections to retrieve a subset of fields instead of entire object?

Tags: spring-data, ignite, gridgain

I am wondering if Apache Ignite Spring Data implementation supports the concept of [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to facilitate retrieving only a subset of the fields/attributes of cache entities instead of fetching the entire entity which may have lots of columns.

In the docs i see an example where only one attribute of the cache entity is fetched as reproduced below.

```
 /**
 * Getting ids of all the Person satisfying the custom query from {@link Query} annotation.
 *
 * @param orgId Query parameter.
 * @param pageable Pageable interface.
 * @return A list of Persons' ids.
 */
@Query("SELECT id FROM Person WHERE orgId > ?")
public List<Long> selectId(long orgId, Pageable pageable);
```

Taking the above example, how does one do this if one needs BOTH the "id" & "firstName", "lastName" of "Person" entity instead of just the "id" as above?

Thanks

UPDATE (Post the answer from @alamar):
Thanks @alamar! I am also reproducing the method declaration & its usage code from Spring Data Test code so its easy for others to follow the answer.

```
/** */
@Query("SELECT _key, secondName FROM Person WHERE firstName REGEXP ?")
public List<List> selectSeveralField(String val, Pageable pageable);

/** */
public void testSelectSeveralFields() {
    List<List> lists = repo.selectSeveralField("^[a-z]+$", new PageRequest(2, 6));

    assertEquals(6, lists.size());

    for (List list : lists) {
        assertEquals(2, list.size());

        assertTrue(list.get(0) instanceof Integer);
    }
}
```

However having Spring Data Projections type mechanism which does away with troublesome casting in user code would have been nicer.

Comment: Thanks to @alamar we know one way to do this, i am reproducing below code from Spring Data test that shows the usage for others

`
    public void testSelectSeveralFields() {
        List<List> lists = repo.selectSeveralField("^[a-z]+$", new PageRequest(2, 6));

        assertEquals(6, lists.size());

        for (List list : lists) {
            assertEquals(2, list.size());

            assertTrue(list.get(0) instanceof Integer);
        }
    }
`

However Spring Data Projections type mechanism which does away with troublesome casting in user code would have been nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Spring Data test:

```
@Query("SELECT _key, secondName FROM Person WHERE firstName REGEXP ?")
public List<List> selectSeveralField(String val, Pageable pageable);
```

E.g. yes, you can list multiple fields and get list of lists (tuples) of those fields.

Comment: Thanks @alamar! I understand in this method it would return a generic list type & the user code can then cast to the target types after getting from the inner list. That is good, however do you know if the more cleaner Projections mechanism from Spring Data is supported here?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you try? If it does not, can you file a JIRA ticket?

Comment: Sure @alamar , i will try & let you know...will also file the ticket if it doesn't.